# JUnit 4 annotations not working when extending AndroidTestCase class

Tags: java, android, junit, android-testing

Hello I am doing the testing section for my sqlite db. I have used JUnit before but I learned I have to extend `AndroidTestCase` to get a mock context. However, when I try to catch exceptions (like in JUnit) the compiler is complaining. Why is this since Android ships with JUnit 4 now?

class example for reference:

```
public class MyTest extends AndroidTestCase {

   @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class) //<-- this does not work
   public void testRandomMethod() {
     callRandomMethod()  //Throws NullPointerException
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not use `AndroidTestCase` it's deprecated in `N`.

Comment: what can I used instead? @MyDogTom

Comment: Don't extend any class. The `@Test` annotation is all you need (and the `org.junit.Assert` class for assertions or some other assertion library). Please hava look into the `AndroidTestCase` class how it creates the mock context and then create it by yourself. Maybe there is another solution, but I don't have experience with Android.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `AndroidTestCase`
2. Use `@Runwith(AndroidJunit4.class)`

For context, 
Use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you extend `AndroidTestCase` then your test is considered to be a JUnit 3 test, because it extends JUnit's `TestCase` class. Don't extend `AndroidTestCase` if you're writing a JUnit 4 test.

Comment: Hmm it seems weird that the documentation says it supports Junit4 but then it does not. Do you know why? (just being curious)

Comment: JUnit 4 still supports JUnit 3 tests. The JUnit style that is used depends on how you write your tests (whether you extend `TestCase` or not).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your minimal setup for JUnit4 tests should be like this.

- `build.gradle`

`testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`

`testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'`

- add a test to `src/test/java` folder
- the simplest test will look like this

```java
public class ExceptionExpectationTest {

    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void shouldThrowException() throws Exception {
        callRandomMethod();
    }

    private static void callRandomMethod() {
        //test will fail because we do not throw NPE
    }
}
```

PS. For more information take a look at these projectes (
[android-testing-templates](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates) and 
[qualitymatters](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/qualitymatters)).
They have pure junit tests among other types of tests.